# numpy.all with integer arguments returns an integer

Tags: python, numpy

Why do this happen?

```
>>> map(numpy.all, range(-2, 3))
[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Is it intentional or is the integer just falling through a crack?

Does it have to do with:

```
>>> map(numpy.all, [False, True])
[False, True]
```

I'm running `Numpy 1.8.0.dev-74b08b3` and `Python 2.7.3`

Comment: I get `[True, True, False, True, True]`, on Python 2.7.3, NumPy 1.6.1.  What versions of Python and NumPy are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce the OP's output in 1.7.1.

Comment: What do you expect `np.all(-2)` to return?

Comment: @BiRico I expect either ValueError or True, mostly ValueError :)
I accidentally wrote `np.all(1)` that is how I found out about it.

Comment: This is smelling like a NumPy bug to me; using `all` on a scalar is an odd enough thing to do that it probably doesn't matter, but apparently zero-dimensional arrays behave this way, too:  `numpy.all(numpy.ones(()))` gives `1.0` for me on NumPy 1.7.1.

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map(numpy.all, range(-2,3))` is actually creating a list with:

```
[numpy.all(-2), numpy.all(-1), numpy.all(0), numpy.all(1), numpy.all(2)]
```

giving

```
[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

If you did `map(lambda x: numpy.all([x]), range(-2,3))`, it would do:

```
[numpy.all([-2]), numpy.all([-1]), numpy.all([0]), numpy.all([1]), numpy.all([2])]
```

giving

```
[True, True, False, True, True]
```

As posted by @Mark Dickinson, there is a known issue with `numpy.all` in which it returns the input value instead of `True` or `False` for some inputs. In your second example `map(numpy.all, [False, True])` does exactly as before, returning the input value.