# Odd behavior of numpy.all with object dtypes

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array of `dtype=object`, `numpy.all/any` return the last object.  For example:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> x = np.array(list(ascii_lowercase), dtype=object)
>>> x.all()
'z'
```

In researching this issue, I couldn't find much except for [this seemingly unrelated SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426547/numpy-all-with-integer-arguments-returns-an-integer) which led me to find out that this is an open bug in numpy (as of March 2015): [first report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4352) and [more relevant issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5267).  Posting this so others grappling with this can find this information out more efficiently.

Comment: So, this isn't really a question, is it?  This is useful to know, but I don't think SO is the place to post it.

Comment: Where is a better place to post?  Should we vote to close as a duplicate of the SO post cited above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `numpy` version `1.8.2`, `np.any` and `np.all` behave as classic short circuit logical and/or functions.  LISP behavor comes to mind.  Python's `and` and `or` operators do this.

Some examples:

```
In [203]: np.all(np.array([[1,2],1,[],[1,2,3]],dtype=object))
Out[203]: []

In [204]: np.any(np.array([[1,2],1,[],[1,2,3]],dtype=object))
Out[204]: [1, 2]

In [205]: np.any(np.array([0,[],[1,2],1,[],[1,2,3]],dtype=object))
Out[205]: [1, 2]

In [206]: np.all(np.array([True,False,[1,2],1,[],[1,2,3]],dtype=object))
Out[206]: False
```

`np.all` returns the first item that is logically False; else the last item. `np.any` the first item that is logically True; else the last item.

In the LISP world this is regarded as a useful feature.  Not only does it stop evaluating elements as soon as the result is clear, but the identity of that return value can be used.

Is there a way of replicating this behavior using the `and/or` operators and some sort of map or reduce?

```
In [8]: 0 or [] or [1,2] or 1 or [1,2,3]
Out[8]: [1, 2]

???([0,[],[1,2],1,[1,2,3]])
```

---

as suggested in the comment:

```
In [26]: reduce(lambda a,b:a and b, np.array([1,2,3,[1,2,3]],dtype=object))
Out[26]: [1, 2, 3]
```

This might not actually short circuit the whole loop.  Rather it short circuits each step, and propagates that value forward.  Using `lambda a,b:b and a` returns the 1st item in the list, not the last.  Timings could be used to test whether it is looping through the whole array (or not).

---

`np.all` is a `ufunc` that is defined as `np.logical_and.reduce`.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/_methods.py

```
umr_all = um.logical_and.reduce
def _all(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
    return umr_all(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
```

`logical_and` for dtype=object is defined in `c` source

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/funcs.inc.src

```
/* Emulates Python's 'a and b' behavior */
static PyObject *
npy_ObjectLogicalAnd(PyObject *i1, PyObject *i2)
```

similarly for `np.any`.  Numeric dtype versions are defined else where.

There's a patch that forces `np.all/any` to return `dtype=bool`.  But by calling `np.logical_all` directly you can control this yourself.

```
In [304]: np.logical_or.reduce(np.array([0,[1,2,3],4],dtype=object))
Out[304]: [1, 2, 3]

In [305]: np.logical_or.reduce(np.array([0,[1,2,3],4],dtype=object),dtype=bool)
Out[305]: True
```

Comment: I think reducing with `lambda x,y: x and y` would work to implement `all`, no?