# numpy versions - "all" function returns different values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

i'm trying to run the same code on different machines which run different numpy versions and i think that there is some inconsistency:

machine with old numpy version:

```
np.version.version
> '1.5.1'
np.array([[1,1],[1,None]]).all(axis=0)
> array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

machine with new numpy version:

```
np.version.version
> '1.8.2'
np.array([[1,1],[1,None]]).all(axis=0)
> array([1, None], dtype=object)
```

finally i found that you can get the results using dtype=bool:

```
np.array([[1,1],[1,None]]).all(axis=0,dtype=bool)
> array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 1):

With the `None`, you array is `dtype=object`.  This behavior was noted and explored a couple of months ago:

[Odd behavior of numpy.all with object dtypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321652/odd-behavior-of-numpy-all-with-object-dtypes/31330904#31330904)