# why all() without arguments on a data frame column(series of object type) in pandas returns last value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a code that looks like this.

```
   dict = {"country": ["Brazil", "Russia", "India", "China", "South Africa"],
   "capital": ["Brasilia", "Moscow", "New Dehli", "Beijing", "Pretoria"],
   "area": [8.516, 17.10, 3.286, 9.597, 1.221],
   "population": [200.4, 143.5, 1252, 1357, 52.98] }

   import pandas as pd
   brics = pd.DataFrame(dict)

   print(brics['capital'].all())
   #the above code prints Pretoria

   print(brics['area'].all())
   #the above code prints True

   print(brics['population'].all())
   #the above code prints True

   print(brics['country'].all())
   #the above code prints South Africa
```

My question is why the code prints True for float type series but prints the last value in the column for object type. I want a result that just says "True" or "False". Kindly help me.

Comment: `brics.all()['capital']` seems to work. I.e. if you do `DataFrame.all` instead and only then look for the series.

Comment: @Roope Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me why the above code prints True for float type series and last value of the column for object type?

Comment: No idea, at least the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html#pandas.Series.all) does not seem to make this very obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you observe reflects precisely the behaviour of NumPy `object` dtype arrays [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321652/odd-behavior-of-numpy-all-with-object-dtypes):

```
brics_np = brics.values  # NumPy array representation

brics_np[:, 0].all()                # 'South Africa'
brics_np[:, 1].all()                # 'Pretoria'
brics_np[:, 2].astype(float).all()  # True
brics_np[:, 3].astype(float).all()  # True
```

This shouldn't be a surprise, since the Pandas library is built on NumPy arrays. You can convert to `bool` explicitly first for your desired result:

```
brics_np[:, 0].astype(bool).all()     # True
brics_np[:, 1].astype(bool).all()     # True
brics['capital'].astype(bool).all()   # True
brics['country'].astype(bool).all()   # True

np.array(['', 'hello'], dtype=object).astype(bool).all()  # False
```

The final example demonstrates that an empty string will yield `False`, since `bool('')` returns `False`.